# Frostwire Installation Problem

Tags: apt, dpkg, skype

I've been using Ubuntu for a while now but am not very proficient with some of the more technical stuff.

Recently I have had trouble with Skype and Frostwire, two programmes that used to work perfectly. Having contacted Skype, I've been informed that my OS is now outdated but that I may be able to download a compatible version in a fortnight or so.

Meanwhile, I recently tried to update Frostwire (which had stopped working for some reason). I uninstalled and attempted to reinstall it, however, every time I attempted to do so I got the same message:

```
(Reading database ... 161198 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking frostwire (from .../frostwire-5.7.6.all.deb) ...
dpkg-deb: file `/home/david/Downloads/frostwire-5.7.6.all.deb' contains ununders
tood data member data.tar.xz     , giving up
dpkg: error processing /home/david/Downloads/frostwire-5.7.6.all.deb (--install)
:
 subprocess dpkg-deb --fsys-tarfile returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /home/david/Downloads/frostwire-5.7.6.all.deb
```

Basically, I have two questions:

1) Is it time I upgraded my OS?

Distribution name & version is Linux Mint 9 Isadora. Kernel version: Linux david-laptop 2.6.32-21-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 16 08:09:38 UTC 2010 x 86_64 GNU/Linux

2) If not, what can I do about the problem I have encountered installing Frostwire?

Answer (score 0):

1.
Yes. You should update your OS. Mint 9 ended it's support in April 2013 according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_Mint_releases.

2.
I believe the problems you had installing skype and frostwire will be fixed with a newer OS, like mint 17 (yes, the newest is number 17).